# SQL COUNT(column_name) from table name for all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have around 1000 columns. Can we get numbers records of each column in a table, by excluding null values of each field.
SQL COUNT(column_name) from table name query excludes null values. But doing this manually for 1000 columns is not possible. Please let me know if there is any other procedure to do it.

Comment: Do you really have 1000 columns in a single table?

Comment: yes GMB, I have access to 600 columns, which is in a view

Comment: You can create a script to generate it and then just execute it by `EXEC (@sql)`

Comment: I can't imagine 600 columns is very practical to work with, even if it's a view. As to answer your question, if it were me, I'd rely on dynamic SQL to write the query for me, because I'm way too lazy for that sort of thing. 

I.e. iterate through sys.columns for the particular view, and use that to construct the dynamic sql.

Comment: Can you please, let me know the quer.. how to iterate the sys.columns one please

Comment: Do you want a single result row with 1000 columns or one result row per column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with dynamic SQL:

```
/* Param var of the table to be queried */
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(50) = 'Misc';

/* Build a list of column names to count */

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''; -- Important to initialize to an empty string.

SELECT @sql = @sql 
    + CASE WHEN LEN( @sql ) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
    + CASE TYPE_NAME( system_type_id )
        WHEN 'text' THEN 'COUNT( CAST([' + [name] + '] AS varchar(1) ) ) AS [' + [name] + '_count]'
        ELSE 'COUNT( [' + [name] + '] ) AS [' + [name] + '_count]'
    END
FROM [sys].[columns] WHERE 
    [object_id] = OBJECT_ID ( @Table );

/* Complete and execute dynamic statement */

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @sql + ' FROM ' + @Table + ';';
EXEC( @sql );
```

**Teradata conversion:**
https://www.jooq.org/translate/

```
declare Table varchar(50) default 'tblOrders';
declare sql varchar(32000) default '';
select ((@sql + case
  when length(@sql) > 0 then ', '
  else ''
end) + case TYPE_NAME(system_type_id)
  when 'text' then (('COUNT( CAST([' + "name" + '] AS varchar(1) ) ) AS [') + "name" + '_count]')
  else (('COUNT( [' + "name" + '] ) AS [') + "name" + '_count]')
end) @sql
from "sys"."columns"
where "object_id" = OBJECT_ID(@Table);
set sql = (('SELECT ' + @sql + ' FROM ') + @Table + ';');
```

Comment: I made a minor edit to exclude `text` columns as those will break the COUNT function.

Comment: thanks a lot!! is there possibility that you can re-write this query in teradata

Comment: @Akhira I'm not familiar with Teradata, but here's an online tool that may help you convert it: `https://www.jooq.org/translate/`  I did, however, update my example to also include the counts for text fields. I also ran the conversion for Teradata and updated my answer.

Comment: The "translation" by Jooq is, ahem, crappy :-)

Comment: In this particular case, crappy means useless.  That converted query is in no way valid sql for Teradata.

Comment: Yes, it can't translate procedural logic very well yet, specifically for Teradata, it isn't supported yet. There's currently no error in cases when something is not supported - it just reproduces a "default" interpretation of the input syntax.